# Enviar un string por socket para dar ordenes al servidor

Tags: python, socket

Tengo 2 programas:

1. tracker.py: realiza los calculos necesarios para apuntar una antena en elevación y azimut a un satélite en base a los datos TLE de celestrak
2. client.py: establece una conexion por socket con un servidor que le da las órdenes a los dos servomotores que apuntan a la antena

Para ello tengo que enviarle en tiempo real los calculos realizados por el tracker en un string especifico: `str("P" + azimut + elevacion)`

La duda que me surge es si ¿tengo que definirlos como funciones en un mismo programa o llamar las variables calculadas de un programa a otro?¿se puede hacer esto?
Adjunto los códigos

tracker.py

```
import time, datetime, ephem
from math import *

ec1_tle = {"Norad": "ESTCUBE 1",
           "Linea1": "1 39161U 13021C   21026.18622615  .00000188  00000-0  37342-4 0  9999",
           "Linea2": "2 39161  97.9502 110.5937 0008490 244.1514 115.8810 14.72415311414813"}

Pontevedra = ("42.4200", "-8.640", "0")

class Tracker():
    def __init__(self, satelite, estacion=("42.4200", "-8.640", "0")):

        self.estacion = ephem.Observer()
        self.estacion.lat = estacion[0]
        self.estacion.lon = estacion[1]
        self.estacion.elevation = int(estacion[2])
        self.satelite = ephem.readtle(
            satelite["Norad"], satelite["Linea1"], satelite["Linea2"])
            

    def set_epoch(self, epoch=time.time()):
        ''' sets epoch when parameters are observed '''

        self.estacion.date = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(epoch)
        self.satelite.compute(self.estacion)

    def azimuth(self):
        ''' returns satelite azimuth in degrees '''
        return degrees(self.satelite.az)

    def elevation(self):
        ''' returns satelite elevation in degrees '''
        return degrees(self.satelite.alt)

    def latitude(self):
        ''' returns satelite latitude in degrees '''
        return degrees(self.satelite.sublat)

    def longitude(self):
        ''' returns satelite longitude in degrees '''
        return degrees(self.satelite.sublong)

    def range(self):
        ''' returns satelite range in meters '''
        return self.satelite.range

    def ecef_coordinates(self):
        ''' returns satellite earth centered cartesian coordinates'''
        
        x, y, z = self._aer2ecef(self.azimuth(), self.elevation(), self.range(), float(
            self.estacion.lat), float(self.estacion.lon), self.estacion.elevation)
        return x, y, z

    def _aer2ecef(self, azimuthDeg, elevationDeg, slantRange, obs_lat, obs_long, obs_alt):

        # site ecef in meters
        sitex, sitey, sitez = llh2ecef(obs_lat, obs_long, obs_alt)

        # some needed calculations
        senlat = sin(radians(obs_lat))
        senlon = sin(radians(obs_long))
        coslat = cos(radians(obs_lat))
        coslon = cos(radians(obs_long))

        azRad = radians(azimuthDeg)
        elRad = radians(elevationDeg)

        # az,el,range to sez convertion
        SUR = -slantRange * cos(elRad) * cos(azRad)
        ESTE = slantRange * cos(elRad) * sin(azRad)
        CENIT = slantRange * sin(elRad)

        x = (senlat * coslon * SUR) + (-senlon * ESTE) + \
            (coslat * coslon * CENIT) + sitex
        y = (senlat * senlon * SUR) + (coslon * ESTE) + \
            (coslat * senlon * zenith) + sitey
        z = (-coslat * SUR) + (senlat * CENIT) + sitez

        return x, y, z

tracker = Tracker(satelite=ec1_tle, estacion=Pontevedra)
while 1:
    tracker.set_epoch(time.time())

    print('Time:', time.ctime(time.time()))
  
    print("Calculado desde: (42.395 N ; 8.708 W)\n")
   
    print("A continuación se muestra en pantalla el Azimut:\n")

    print(tracker.azimuth())
   
    print("A continuación se muestra en pantalla la Elevación:\n")

    print("elevación  : %0.2f" % tracker.elevation())
    
    AZ = str(tracker.azimuth())
    EL = str(tracker.elevation())
    mensaje = "P" + " " + AZ + " " + EL
    print(mensaje)

 
    time.sleep(2)
```

client.py

```
import socket, time, select


# local host IP '127.0.0.1' 
host = '127.0.0.1'

# Define the port on which you want to connect 
port = 4533
address = (host,port)
print("Se va a establecer la conexión...\n")
FORMAT = 'ascii'

#Creamos el socket y lo conectamos por el socket 4533 a localhost
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
result_of_check = s.connect_ex(address)

def Client(): 

    while True:
        print("Conexion establecida")
        message = "P 180.0 0.0\r"
    
        # message sent to server 
        s.send(message.encode(FORMAT)) 
    
        infds, outfds, errfds = select.select([s], [s], [], 5)
        if len(infds) != 0:
            data = s.recv(1024)
            if len(data) != 0:
                print('Received from the server :',str(data.decode(FORMAT)))        
        if len(outfds) != 0:
                print("Esperando...\n")
    
        time.sleep(5)
    # Close the connection 
    s.close()
    print("Un saludo")
      

def Comprobacion():
    
    if result_of_check == 0:
       print("Se va a establecer conexión...\n")
       Client()

    else: 
       print("No es posible establecer conexion\n")

    s.close()   

Comprobacion()
```

Comment: Veo dos cosas: Una es que entras en bucles de los que no puedes salir nunca. Si utilizas un while:true asegurate de que escapas de alguna forma con alguna condicion. Lo segundo es que igual que implementas un "cliente", no has implementado el servidor. Como sugerencia podrias primero escribir un cliente y servidor simple y que funcione y luego trasladar eso a tu programa.

Comment: Gracias. El servidor ya está implementado, es un programa a parte. ¿que clase de salidas le puedo dar al bucle?¿con ué argumentos?

Comment: Por ejemplo podrías implementar algún tipo de "watchdog" que si no recibe respuesta en x minutos que cierre la conexión y reinicie el server en caso de que ocurra algún problema o se cuelgue el sistema. Porque sino, por ejemplo, nunca se va a ejecutar el s.close() que está después del while puesto que nunca sale. Para enviar datos a través de la red normalmente se usa algún tipo de encapsulamiento serializado como podría ser ''MessagePack" o 'pickle' (este ultimo es nativo de python pero no se recomienda porque es más vulnerable a fallos de seguridad si no se implementa bien)

Comment: Gracias. Lo probaré